# access an array of type class which is internal in a public class

Tags: c#

I have an internal class

```
namespace commonNamespace
{
    internal class A{}
}
```

i have another public class within the same assembly

```
public class B{}
```

I want to declare an array of type A in classB.
ex:

```
namespace commonNamespace
{
    public class B
    {
        A[] array;
    }
}
```

I am getting inconsistent accessibility Level error message.Please let me know how can i do this.

Comment: Since `A[] array` is private (due to lack of an access modifier), I don't see why this is a problem.  Is this field actually public?

Comment: What you have here should be fine. It's only an issue if `array` is declared public or protected.

Comment: The code you have posted compiles without issue.

Answer (score 2):

You must have a public/protected field or property in `B` exposing some instance(s) of type `A`. Mark that as internal and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Just add access modifier to the field Array:

```
public class B
{
   internal A[] array;
}
```

This is the Access Modifiers hierarchy:

```
 public > protected > internal > internal protected > private
```

So just choose anything below protected and you will be fine.

Comment: That *shouldn't* help - as the default is to be private. So by declaring the `array` variable `internal`, you're actually *increasing* its visibility.

Comment: The access modifiers hierarchy is wrong, `internal protected` means `internal` or `protected`. So it can be accessed internally by any class, or only accessed by derived classes in other assemblies.

Comment: sorry i have the array object inside an interface which is public because i want to only expose the interface outside the assembly.But the class should not be exposed outside.